# Textbutton and texture atlas in libgdx

Tags: android, button, timer, libgdx

I have a textbutton with texture atlas

```
 TextButton.TextButtonStyle style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle(); 
        style.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttonup");
        style.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttondown");
        style.font = font;
```

when I press the button on the exit button I have the code

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

and it work, I can see the style.down on the button event touchdown. when I use it in the button play I can't see the style.down. why? I tryed with a timer

```
      Timer.schedule(new Timer.Task() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myGame.setScreen(new GameScreen(myGame));
            }
        }, 500);
```

but the game screen run and I can't see the button as pressed. please could you tell me a possible solution for this problem?

edit:

```
button.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

        myGame.setScreen(new GameScreen(myGame));
        return true;
    }

    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {


    }
});


style.up = buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttonup");
style.down = buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttondown");
style.font = font;

button = new TextButton("Play", style); 
button.setHeight(300 * scaley); 
button.setWidth(800 * scalex);
button.setPosition(Constants.APP_WIDTH / 2 - button.getWidth() / 2, Constants.APP_HEIGHT / 2 + button.getHeight());
```

Comment: The code you post should show a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help the quickest. Otherwise you'll get questions asking for more and more of your code until the problem is come across. For instance, you should probably show the code for your "play" button, rather the working code that runs the game screen?

Comment: added the button.listener....

Comment: Can you add where you instantiate `button`?

Comment: added the code for style and textbutton

Comment: found the solution!!!! myGame.setScreen(new GameScreen(myGame)); in the touchup :)))))))

Comment: Use ChangeListener instead of InputListener. Otherwise the button will not behave as expected by users.